# Waiting for volume to be created either by external provisioner "pd.csi.storage.gke.io" or manually created by system administrator. Windows minikube

Tags: storage, cluster-computing, minikube, volume, kubernetes-pvc

I created a PVC and then tried to expand the size of the volume claim.

Volume expansion is set to true as below:

```
minikube kubectl -- get sc
NAME                 PROVISIONER                RECLAIMPOLICY   VOLUMEBINDINGMODE   ALLOWVOLUMEEXPANSION   AGE
fast                 kubernetes.io/gce-pd       Delete          Immediate           true                   55m
standard (default)   k8s.io/minikube-hostpath   Delete          Immediate           true                   156m
```

I patched the PVC using kubectl edit.

When I described the PVC I get the below message:

```
Normal  ExternalProvisioning  93s (x177 over 61m)  persistent volume-controller  waiting for a volume to be created, either by external provisioner "pd.csi.storage.gke.io" or manually created by the system administrator.
```

Should I create a volume here? Please Help.
Please refer this [code](https://github.com/scriptcamp/kubernetes-mongodb) to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It is not working because GKE is not setup. You need to setup it first then provision volumes through Storage Classes.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are creating a PVC using a GKE provision, in this case, you don't need to create PV, only PVC example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: volume-name
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 3Gi
```

Google is only allowing `ReadWriteOnce` and `ReadOnlyOnce` for this type of dynamic provisioning yet. Basically, after applying this config you still need to create a pod to consume this volume. After this the creation and bind are complete.